# lcm and divisibility proof

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Having troubles trying to solve these questions about divisibility and LCM.

For (a), isn't that just the definition of LCM? If, $a|k$ and $b|k$, then $k$ is the $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$?

Not sure where to start for (b)

Comment: The usual name for the number with property a) is "distinguished common multiple". Of course, in the set of integers, this is the lcm, but this is precisely what you are supposed to show. Also, to answer your question properly, you should specify if you can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, Bezout's identity... etc.

Comment: First question, it could be much bigger. For example, let $a=4$ and $b=6$. The lcm is $12$, but $a$ and $b$ both divide $k=6000$.  Or much smaller, $k=-300$.

Answer (score 0):

$[a,b]$ is basically the union of 2sets ,one has the factors of $a$ and other has factors of $b$

Now,

Let $\mathbb A$ be the set of primes present in $a$

And,

Let $\mathbb B$ be the set of primes present in b

Then $[a,b]$ is $\mathbb A \cup \mathbb B$

So $[a,b]$ contains primes present in $a$ and $ b$ but takes into consideration $\mathbb A \cap\mathbb B$ once.

But now,

$a|k$ and $b|k$ ,

So $k$ may contain another prime or may contain the same primes more than those present in $\mathbb A \cup \mathbb B$
So $[a,b]|k$

Another approach to the problem:-

Since by definition  LCM of $a$ &$b$ is the **least common** multiple, then $k$ is the  common multiple which is sure to be divided by $[a,b]$

Now for the second part,

Let $a$ be $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$

And $b$ be $p_1^{\beta_1}\cdot p_2^{\beta_2}...p_m^{\beta_m}$

Where $m\geqslant k$(*you may even consider the contrary*)

$(a,b)=p_1^{min({\alpha_1},{\beta_1})} \cdot p_2^{min(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}...p_k^{min(\alpha_k,\beta_k)}$

Now ,

$[a,b]=p_1^{max({\alpha_1},{\beta_1})} \cdot p_2^{max(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}...p_k^{max(\alpha_k,\beta_k)}\cdot p_{k+1}^{\beta_{k+1}}...p_m^{\beta_m}$

$(a,b)\cdot [a,b]=p_1^{min(\alpha_1,\beta_1)+max(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}.p_2^{min(\alpha_2,\beta_2)+max(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}...p_k^{min(\alpha_k,\beta_k)+max(\alpha_k,\beta_k)}.p_{k+1}^{\beta_{k+1}}...p_m^{\beta_m}$
Now min(a,b)=either a or b and max will be the other

So $min(a,b)+max(a,b)=a+b
$

so we can go on to split them into products using product law of Indices and then group them as per $a$ and $b$.

So the resultant is 
(a,b).[a,b]=a.b

From this you get your result